# usage of would have + past participle

Tags: grammaticality

Is this sentence grammatically correct ?

- They were not going to stop no matter how hard you would have tried .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> You would have tried.

This is expressing a hypothetical situation (modally remote) where *would* marks the situation as unlikely and *have* marks past time, e.g.

> If you had been there, you would have tried.

*no matter* introduces an exhaustive conditional, so

> no matter how hard you would have tried

is in this case our condition (protasis), and

> they were not going to stop

is our outcome (apodosis) in a remote conditional construction.

There are some general rules for these constructions (CaGEL p751)

> The form of remote conditionals
>
> ---
>
> Tense and mood restrictions
>
> The verb of the protasis must be the irrealis form *were* or a preterite
> with the modal remoteness meaning. The verb of the apodosis must be a
> modal auxiliary; this too must be a modally remote preterite, except
> where the modal has only a present tense form.

So it follows that your example is ungrammatical because the verb in the outcome (apodosis)

> They **were** not going to stop

is not a modal auxiliary.

It could be fixed thusly:

> No matter how hard you would have tried, they **would not have stopped**.

Comment: 'They were not going to stop no matter how hard you tried' sounds acceptable in an informal register to my ears.

Comment: Sure, but that would no longer be a remote conditional as the preterite _tried_ simply marks past time, not modal remoteness. This question was concerned with the _would have_ + past participle construction.

Answer (score -1):

Grammatically? Not in my opinion. I'd leave out the "would have". IMO saying/writing "would have" and "tried" is redundant since they're both relating to something (in this case "trying") that is past tense.